# How to add Email verification in Django Rest- Framework?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework-jwt

I add Email verification or Email sending option in Django but in Rest framework when i try sending email from serializer class it doesn't respond. Anybody give me some idea's how can i do this ?

My Views.py code is :

```
class MyProfileViewSets(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
""" This is for handling updating , creating and editing serializser"""

serializer_class=serializers.MyUserSerializser
queryset=models.MyUser.objects.all()
authentication_classes=(TokenAuthentication,)
permission_classes=(permissions.UpdateProfile,)
filter_backends=(filters.SearchFilter,)
search_fields=('name','email')
```

My serializers.py code is in here :

```
class MyUserSerializser(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = MyUser
    fields =('id','name','email','password')
    extra_kwargs = {'password':{'write_only':True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user=MyUser(
            email=validated_data['email'],
            name=validated_data['name']
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

I don't know how to send email to the user to let user know their account is successfully created. I try writing code in serializer but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hey Aashish, it's good practice to let us know what you have tried and also to post 
 relevant portions of your work so far.

Comment: Also add your views.py file in the question

Comment: i updated my post please give a look.